# SOLR SORTING EXPRESSION

Tags: solr

I am working on solr for search. I required to perform a expression sort such that :

ORDER BY ((IF AVAILABLE IN (1,2,3),100,IF(AVAILABLE IN (4,5,6),80,100)) + IF(PRICE>1000,70,40)) DESC

Comment: Instead of trying to handle this complexity @ query time, you can populate these fields at index time and use that field for sorting.

Comment: i want it at run time only
obviously vales 1,2,3 is at run time and can vary

Comment: using "MAP" function u can do somewhat close to ur requirement.
still if else if , i dnt know if its implemented in solr